# Infinite scroll loop in wordpress elementor website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

i have built a website in elementor, and i want to achieve infinite scroll loop so when user reaches end of the content on a page, it keeps repeating endlessly in a loop. something like this: https://www.juliajohnson.com/

i didn't find any wp plugin that offers such function, however i did find js from https://codepen.io/vincentorback/pen/zxRyzj:

```
var doc = window.document,
  context = doc.querySelector('.js-loop'),
  clones = context.querySelectorAll('.is-clone'),
  disableScroll = false,
  scrollHeight = 0,
  scrollPos = 0,
  clonesHeight = 0,
  i = 0;

function getScrollPos () {
  return (context.pageYOffset || context.scrollTop) - (context.clientTop || 0);
}

function setScrollPos (pos) {
  context.scrollTop = pos;
}

function getClonesHeight () {
  clonesHeight = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < clones.length; i += 1) {
    clonesHeight = clonesHeight + clones[i].offsetHeight;
  }

  return clonesHeight;
}

function reCalc () {
  scrollPos = getScrollPos();
  scrollHeight = context.scrollHeight;
  clonesHeight = getClonesHeight();

  if (scrollPos <= 0) {
    setScrollPos(1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
  }
}

function scrollUpdate () {
  if (!disableScroll) {
    scrollPos = getScrollPos();

    if (clonesHeight + scrollPos >= scrollHeight) {
      // Scroll to the top when you’ve reached the bottom
      setScrollPos(1); // Scroll down 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
      disableScroll = true;
    } else if (scrollPos <= 0) {
      // Scroll to the bottom when you reach the top
      setScrollPos(scrollHeight - clonesHeight);
      disableScroll = true;
    }
  }

  if (disableScroll) {
    // Disable scroll-jumping for a short time to avoid flickering
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      disableScroll = false;
    }, 40);
  }
}

function init () {
  reCalc();
  
  context.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate);
  }, false);

  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);
  }, false);
}

if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
  init()
} else {
  doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false)
}








// Just for this demo: Center the middle block on page load
window.onload = function () {
  setScrollPos(Math.round(clones[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + getScrollPos() - (context.offsetHeight - clones[0].offsetHeight) / 2));
};
```

i did try adding js and given selector class to elementor section but i didn't seem to work. can anyone with js expertise guide how this can be achieved?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Where does it load more data?